# Get result from two mysql tables using group

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a solution to get result from two MYSQL tables

First table is: rate_table

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`rate` float(5,4) NOT NULL,
`amount` float(12,2) NOT NULL,


INSERT INTO `rate_table` (`id`, `rate`, `amount`) VALUES
(1, 4.1555, 100),
(2, 4.1555, 100),
(3, 4.4444, 50),
```

second table is: trans_table

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`amount` float(12,2) NOT NULL,
`rate_id` int(11) NOT NULL,

INSERT INTO `trans_table` (`id`,  `amount`, `rate_id`) VALUES
(1, 20, 1),
(2, 30, 1);
```

Now I need group results from rate_table by `rate_table.rate`, sum `rate_table.amount` - sum `trans_table.amount` where `trans_table.trade_id = rate_table.id` ....

so above example should give result:

```
rate   |sum  | sum - sum second table
4.5555 | 200 | 150 |
4.4444 | 50  | 50  |
```

Comment: what-have-you-tried-so-far? I mean, do you have any partial query that gave you a wrong result?

Comment: have a problem with built query.... because when I'm using group by rate , ids from rate_table are hidden and gets only one id

Comment: post your query in your answer, it will be the starting point for who's going to help you.

Comment: In the `rate_table` why is there rate = 4.1555 twice? Also, rate in expected output is different.

Comment: Consider using DECIMAL instead of FLOAT.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following.

please refer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49f5b/24

```
select rate, sum(rate_table.amount),  IFNULL(sum(rate_table.amount),0) - IFNULL(sum(IFNULL(trans_table.amount,0)),0) from
rate_table  inner join trans_table on trans_table.rate_id = rate_table.id group by rate_table.rate 

UNION

select rate, sum(rate_table.amount),  IFNULL(sum(rate_table.amount),0) from
rate_table  where rate not in (select rate from rate_table where rate in (select rate from rate_table, trans_table where trans_table.rate_id = rate_table.id)) group by rate_table.rate ;
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT rate, ratesum , ratesum-IFNULL(transsum, 0) sum_minus_sum
FROM (SELECT rate, SUM(amount) ratesum
      FROM rate_table
      GROUP BY rate) r
LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT rate_id, SUM(amount) transsum
      FROM trans_table
      GROUP BY rate_id) t
ON r.rate = t.rate_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select rate_table.rate, SUM(rate_table.amount) as sum1,
COALESCE((SUM(rate_table.amount) - SUM(trans_table.amount)),
         SUM(rate_table.amount)) as sum2
from rate_table LEFT join trans_table on 
trans_table.rate_id = rate_table.id
group by rate_table.rate;
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0fe0/10)

Answer (score 0):

I simply modified Barmar's answer a little bit

```
SELECT  rate, ratesum, ratesum - IFNULL(transsum, 0) sum_minus_sum
FROM (  SELECT id, rate, SUM(amount) ratesum
        FROM rate_table
        GROUP BY rate
) r LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT rate_id, SUM(amount) transsum
        FROM trans_table
        GROUP BY rate_id) t
ON r.id = t.rate_id;
```

**EDIT**

Although the above query produces the result given in the answer it still isn't the way to go. By grouping the rates table by rate you lose their id and you cant join with the transaction table properly.